# TypeError: (0 , _material_ui_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.makeStyles) is not a function

Tags: material-ui

I am getting this error when compiling in Layout.js
My code:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

 const useStyles = makeStyles({
     page: {
         background: '#f9f9f9',
         width:'100%'
     },
     drawer:{
         width: drawerWidth

     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

From the error it is clear that `makeStyles` is not available in the dependency `@material-ui/core`.
Use the line below instead to fix the issue where `makeStyles` is imported from `@material-ui/core/styles`

`import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';`